# How to perform specific operation on layer in Keras?

Tags: keras

Is it possible to perform some static computation on layers in Keras? For example, compute squares? Or compute square root of sum of squares?

Comment: Yes, its possible. But you need to provide more detail for a more meaningful answer.

Comment: What details are neede? Can I just raise layer into power layer**2

Comment: Well layers are not numbers, you cannot do an operation on a layer, but you can operate on a layer's output. Is that what you mean? For that you can just use a Lambda layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing the results to another layer, you are probably trying to implement a custom layer.

Keras provides you this guide on creating a custom layer: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

See this for an easier way: https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2016/11/18/for-beginners-writing-a-custom-keras-layer/